# How to fetch large data WCF - Stream or Buffered?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

Currently I'm having a NetTcpBinding with the default Buffered Transport Mode. I'm trying to determine what the best solution is for my request that builds a class that ends up being a large amount of data.

Basically I have a request that comes into WCF to grab a bunch of reporting information and return it to the client. As long as this is under the 64k MaxMessageRecievedSize it is fine, but if it goes over then I end up having an exception.

Should I switch to a Streaming TransferMode and then stream a file back to the client instead since the data could be small or large amounts? Or is it ok to increase the MaxMessageRecievedSize? It seems like a bad idea to increase the MaxMessageRecievedSize because if we have multiple connections to the service all fetching large amounts of data we could potentially have memory issues?

Any thoughts on how I could go about achieving this?

Comment: How large is a large message for you?  These days 64k isn't really all that large.  I wouldn't worry about a message that size (or increasing it within reason) unless you have a very slow server side response, a high level of concurrent traffic, or a very low level of ram.

Comment: Ideally the machine the service will be running on is going to have at least 4GB. However, I'm trying to ensure that we can support small and extremely large files from the beginning. So maybe today report sizes are 64kb or 65mb, but whatever one day they become 5gb+? It seems like the only answer is to stream so that the size is never a factor...

Comment: Use streaming for larger files. Remember, "large" is relative, but I would say anything over 10 MB is large.

Answer (score 2):

For the sizes you mention, you should switch to streaming. There's a detailed document that discusses this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx